# Stickies and Notifications center hybrid

Tags: software-recommendation, notifications, productivity, stickies

The notifications center is always just a swipe away, but I never use it.

Stickies on the contrary I use them a lot, but I cannot easily have them on all desktops, hidden when I don't need them.

It would be perfect to be able to open stickies with the same gesture used for the notifications center, does anybody know if an app like this is available?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the lighter version of Stickies available in the Dashboard.

Then use System Preferences to set a trackpad gesture to activate it. Then stickies are easily accessible while also out of sight when you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd prefer not to use the Dashboard.

Comment: Essentially what you're asking for is to customize the actions initiated by trackpad gestures. This  may not be possible and you need an alternative approach to meet your goals.

Comment: It's already possible to bind a custom action to the `2 fingers scroll from left/top/right/bottom edge` with BetterTouchTool, so those could technically be used to show and hide Stickies, but it wouldn't feel as integrated with the system as the notifications center.

Comment: You can use Notification Center widgets. There are a few for taking notes, and they will be more powerful than Stickies

Comment: @user166405 they're also not free. now we have to pay for what we used to use for 5+ years for free